# Stop axios.post from stringifying my js dict

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, axios

Right now Im posting my reactjs state to my flask backend with axios as such

```
 let data = new FormData()
 for (var key in this.state){
                data.append(key,this.state[key])
        }
return axios.post(`url/database`,data,
                {transformRequest:[],params:{'state':this.data},headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',},})
```

On my flask backend:

```
@app.route('/database',methods = ['POST'])
def upload_data():
     print(request.form.to_dict())
```

Outputs a dictionary where all the arrays,booleans, and ints have been converted to strings.

Is there a way to stop axios from stringifying all of the entries in the dictionary?

Comment: What do you mean stop stringifying? What do you want to send? You have to send to backend a string only

Comment: One of the elements in my dictionary is an array of values, [[1,5,24],[3,2]] for example. If I send this value to the backend, it converts it to a string, which is annoying, since I want it to be sent as an array.

Comment: You can send only string to server then parse it.  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types